# Toggling on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a situation in which I am using Bootstrap collapse to create growing and shrinking content.

I have a class called my-btn which has a background image of a downwards arrow. When I click on this button I want to add a class called open.

```css
    .my-btn{
    background-image:url(../img/template-1/read-more-closed.png);
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:center;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .open{
   background-image:url(../img/template-1/read-more-open.png);
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:center;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <button class="btn my-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" 
                  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">&nbsp;</button>
```

By adding the open class after my-btn, the arrow is changed... but how can I acheive this using CSS/js?

UPDATE

I have tried

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.my-btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
});   
          </script>
```

But on toggle, bootstrap adds the collaPSED CLASS BUT MY CODE IS IGNORED.

Comment: use jquery , .toggleClass()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
.my-btn{
background-image:url(../img/template-1/read-more-closed.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            margin-bottom:50px;
}

.open{
  background-image:url(../img/template-1/read-more-open.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn my-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" 
              aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onclick="this.classList.toggle('open')">&nbsp;</button>
```

The important part is `onclick="this.classList.toggle('open')"`, this JavaScript code will toggle the "open" class (remove it if it exists or add it if it doesn't).

Keep in mind that the `classList.toggle` function is not supported by all browser. You may have to use some polyfill if you want to support all browsers.

Comment: This works very well, but could I ask you to take a guess as to why the seemingly simple JQuery implementation with the use of toggle() did not work?

Comment: It also works with jQuery. You can see that here: https://jsfiddle.net/0jr7v0Ln/ I suggested a vanilla JavaScript solution because I didn't knew that you're going to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly and easily achieve this using an **on click** function combined with a **toggle class** function for adding/removing classes after your button is clicked.

See below for working code.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.my-btn{
    background-image:url(../img/template-1/read-more-closed.png);
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:center;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .open{
   background-image:url(../img/template-1/read-more-open.png);
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:center;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <button class="btn my-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" 
                  aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">&nbsp;</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`toggleClass()` function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
$('.my-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```